# How to link to CSS with htmltools?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, htmltools

I understand htmltools can be used to link to a JavaScript file:

```
htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/mapbox-gl-leaflet/leaflet-mapbox-gl.js")
```

But how would I link to a CSS file, for example:

```
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.11.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Comment: It's a pretty strait-forward translation: `htmltools::tags$link(href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.11.0/mapbox-gl.css", rel="stylesheet")`

Comment: thanks, Flick!  appreciated.